How do i select unique value from CSV column and pass this to an option select box (Remove Duplicates)?
I'm reading the specific column from a CSV file and try to remove duplicate rows of data so i have unique rows only.
How can i retrieve unique rows and display them in the select option?
$company_id = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['company_id']);
$filename = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['filename']);
$csvfile = fopen(dirname(__DIR__, 2)."/feeds/company/" .$company_id ."/" . $filename, "r");
$delimiter = getFileDelimiter(dirname(__DIR__, 2)."/feeds/company/" .$company_id ."/" . $filename);
    
$data = fgetcsv($csvfile, 0, $delimiter);
while (($data = fgetcsv($csvfile, 0, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {  
    // CSV Category Column = 6      
    $category = $data[6];
    echo '<option value = "' . $category  . '">' . $category . '</option>'; 
}

I have tried to put the column data into an array and use unique_array which half works, however by doing this the column data is on a single line rather than seperate lines and line breaks dont appear to be an option with select boxes:
$csvfile = fopen(dirname(__DIR__, 2)."/feeds/company/" .$company_id ."/" . $filename, "r");
$delimiter = getFileDelimiter(dirname(__DIR__, 2)."/feeds/company/" .$company_id ."/" . $filename);
$data = fgetcsv($csvfile, 0, $delimiter);
    
$category = array();        
while (($data = fgetcsv($csvfile, 0, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {      
  // CSV Category Column = 6             
  $category[] = $data[6];
}
$uniquecat = array_unique($category);                   
$new_category = implode(",", $uniquecat);                   
echo '<option value = "' . $new_category  . '">' . $new_category . '</option>';

However the data appears in the select box on a single line with no line breaks
e.g.
one two three four

instead of:
one 
two
three
four

tried method shown above, unable to get array data to seperate lines

You're combining the array into a single string with implode(). Don't do that, loop over the array
$csvfile = fopen(dirname(__DIR__, 2)."/feeds/company/" .$company_id ."/" . $filename, "r");
$delimiter = getFileDelimiter(dirname(__DIR__, 2)."/feeds/company/" .$company_id ."/" . $filename);
fgets($csvfile); // skip header line
    
$category = array();        
while (($data = fgetcsv($csvfile, 0, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {      
  // CSV Category Column = 6             
  $category[] = $data[6];
}

$uniquecat = array_unique($category);                   
foreach ($uniquecat as $cat) {
    echo '<option value = "' . $cat  . '">' . $cat . '</option>';
}

